# Setting width of CheckBoxList Labels to full width (to allow row selection)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, checkboxlist

This seems pretty a straight-forward question, but I could not find a specific answer here (or via Google).

I have an APS.Net `CheckBoxList` inside a overlaid div (emulating a dropdown selection list).

By default the HTML generated for the CheckBoxLIst looks like:

```
<table id="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="ALL" name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownCheckBoxList4$checkBoxList$0" id="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList_0" class="dropdowncheck"><label for="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList_0" class="dropdownlabel">All</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownCheckBoxList4$checkBoxList$1" id="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList_1" class="dropdowncheck"><label for="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList_1" class="dropdownlabel">Item 0</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownCheckBoxList4$checkBoxList$2" id="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList_2" class="dropdowncheck"><label for="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList_2" class="dropdownlabel">Item 1</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownCheckBoxList4$checkBoxList$3" id="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList_3" class="dropdowncheck"><label for="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList_3" class="dropdownlabel">Item 2</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownCheckBoxList4$checkBoxList$4" id="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList_4" class="dropdowncheck"><label for="MainContent_DropDownCheckBoxList4_checkBoxList_4" class="dropdownlabel">Item 3</label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The problem is the individual labels are only the width of the text within then, but I want the entire row to be selectable. Note my control/table has a fixed width, so you do not need to calculate the lengths etc.

All the solutions I have seen suggest using `display: block` or variations, but that causes the text to appear on the line below the checkbox, even set to 90% width as well that does not work on all browers.

**How do I make the label take up the remainder of the line?** A JQuery answer is acceptable (even preferable, as the control is heavily JQuery'ed already), but please post a solution that works on all browsers. You can see from the HTML I am already adding a `dropdowncheck` class to the checkboxes and a `dropdownlabel` class to the labels via JQuery (if that helps give a specific CSS answer).

### Simple solution (based on answer from Henrik):

```
.dropdowncheck
{
    float: left;

.dropdownlabel
{
    display: block;
}
```

So long as the checkboxes and labels have classes assigned (i.e. via JQuery), this works fine.

Comment: SO should never have allowed down-voting questions without penalty. I am getting sick of retaliatory voting from other users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting the label to display:block and giving the checkbox float:left ?

If the text is not horizontally aligned as you want, just set height on the checkbox and give the label an equal line-height.

Comment: It's always the simple things that get missed. Thanks, that works perfectly. Question updated to include your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you're looking for even by pure jQuery. Inspired from [this](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/12/quick-tip-click-table-row-to-trigger-a-checkbox-click) I made
[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/zPQMu/1/). I had to remove the label tags though as their function became deprecated after this approach.

```
$('td').click(function(event){

if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
  $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');

}

})​
```

Spice it up with some css

```
td{
width: 200px;
background: orange;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
cursor: pointer;
}​
```

Comment: +1 for useful information. Not an exact match to the question, but still good to know about. Thanks

Comment: As you mention, the labels interfere with the clicks in this solution, so the labels do need to be removed, unfortunately I am using a CheckBoxList which generates labels.